# replace a word on variable value on php and using it on elseif statements

Tags: php, string, replace

If i have a variable like this on php :

```
$codition = "question_1 == a AND question_2 == b";
```

is there any way to replace the value to be like this :

```
$codition = "$question_1 == 'a' && $question_2 == 'b'";
```

This variable I can use in this condition:

```
 if(echo $codition){
     echo "Success";
 } else {
     echo "fail";
 }
```

The reason I use a variable on condition (if else) because I have a rule in the database, and the value looks like the first value on the variable `$codition`, is it possible to replace a word on variable and using it on `elseif` statements?

Comment: This code is all wrong... You can't use a string as a condition this way, it will always evaluate true.

Comment: If you tell him 'his code is all wrong', also tell him why

Comment: I for one have no idea what it is you are asking or wanting to do. Seeing that this is db related, you should tell us what it is exactly that you wish to do and what results you're getting as compared to what you want.

Comment: You don't need to code like this. Just use the value from the database on your first expression of if.

Comment: @rizal, how do you get that string? Where does it come from? Because you can do `$codition = $question_1 == 'a' && $question_2 == 'b';`

Comment: Personally, I think you should be doing this in the query, but only *you* know what you have and what you want. I'm out.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are off track entirely with your question. Below I attempt to get at your question, but making an educated guess at what you are asking.

Assume:
Var $codition is a condition to check if 'a' or 'b'
Vars $q1codition and $q2codition are used to hold these strings 'a' and 'b'

Then:

```
$q1codition = 'a';
$q2codition = 'b';

if($codition == $q1codition && $codition == $q2codition){
 echo "Success";
 } else {
 echo "fail";
 }
```

Is this what you are getting at?